# Matthew 5:32 - (NASB) Cause Her to Commit Adultery vs. Makes Her a Victim (NIV)

Tags: matthew, word-study

I am trying to understand the different renderings of Matthew 5:32.

> Matthew 5:32 Modern English Version (MEV)
>
> But I say to you that whoever divorces his wife, except for marital
>   unfaithfulness, causes her to commit adultery. And whoever marries her
>   who is divorced commits adultery.
>
> Matthew 5:32 New International Version (NIV)
>
> But I tell you that anyone who divorces his wife, except for sexual
>   immorality, makes her the victim of adultery, and anyone who marries a
>   divorced woman commits adultery.

The difference seems to occur over the verb μοιχευθῆναι (to commit adultery);

> Tense: Aorist 
>   Mood: Infinitive
>   Voice: Passive

Can anyone help me understand the nuances between the forms of these two verbs and why they may have caused a difference in translations?  Thanks!

Comment: Great question. What is the MEV? I haven't come across that acronym before.

Comment: @Steve Taylor - The M.E.V. is the Modern English Version, which is published by Charisma House.  Information can be found here: https://www.biblegateway.com/versions/Modern-English-Version-MEV-Bible/